# Page not found error when trying to use encryption in JAX-RS Jersey REST

Tags: java, security, rest, jersey, jax-rs

I'm using Eclipse to implement REST web services using Jersey. I want all communications to be in https. So, I edited my web.xml to be

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
    <display-name>com.myapp.server</display-name>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
            <param-value>com.myapp.server</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerRequestFilters</param-name>
            <param-value>com.myapp.server.webservices.security.SecurityFilter</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>5</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <!-- Security constraint for the sample application -->
    <security-constraint id="SecurityConstraint_1">
        <!-- This defines the REST resource associated with the constraint. -->
        <web-resource-collection id="WebResourceCollection_1">
            <web-resource-name>Jersey REST Service</web-resource-name>
            <description>Protection area for Rest resource / </description>
            <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
        </web-resource-collection>

        <user-data-constraint id="UserDataConstraint_1">
            <transport-guarantee>CONFIDENTIAL</transport-guarantee>
        </user-data-constraint>
    </security-constraint>
```

Then when testing with normal `http://localhost:8080/com.myapp.server/rest/user/all`, it redirects to `https://localhost:8443/com.myapp.server/rest/user/all`. And then I get Page not found. What am I doing wrong? Anyway to solve this?

Comment: What application server are you using? Did you enable the SSL endpoint for it? And was the port really configured as 8443? Quite unusual, since HTTPS is normally configured to listen to port 443.

Comment: I use TomCat and no I didn't do any further steps like SSL enable ! Pointer to a guide/tutorial?

Comment: Okay, you will need to enable SSL. You can follow this [official guide](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/ssl-howto.html) that walks through the process step by step.

Comment: Could you please send me the link ?

Comment: I included the link in my comment, here it is again: http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/ssl-howto.html

Comment: Thank you. Sorry, I need a new eyeglasses :)